# call two cython functions of same module from c++

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have encountered a strange problem, when calling cython functions from same cython module. Here is a simple example:

**twocythonfunctions.pyx:**

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef public hello1() :
    print('haha1')

cdef public hello2() :
    print('haha2')
```

**main.c**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
#include "twocythonfunctions.h"

void hello_wrapper1()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyInit_twocythonfunctions();
    hello1();
    Py_Finalize();
}

void hello_wrapper2()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    //PyInit_twocythonfunctions();
    hello2();
    Py_Finalize();
}


int main()
{
    hello_wrapper1();
    hello_wrapper2();
    return 1;
}
```

**Makefile**:

```
all:
    cython -3 --cplus twocythonfunctions.pyx
    g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic -c twocythonfunctions.cpp -o twocythonfunctions.o `python3-config --includes`
    g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic -c main.c -o main.o `python3-config --includes`
    g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -o example main.o twocythonfunctions.o `python3-config --ldflags`

clean:
    rm -f example twocythonfunction.{c,h} *.o
```

Compiling and running above code: I got "haha1" and "haha2" printed. However if I **uncomment** the line in main.c. I will get first "haha1" printed and a segment default.

It looks to me that when calling cython function from same module, module initialization can ONLY happen once. I am wondering if cython is designed as this way. If so, what is the reasoning?

More info:

1. I am running it on MacOSX
2. My cython is 0.24.
3. My python is 3.5.1

Some other thoughts:

One may think we can initialize all modules and beginning and then use it. In my application, I only need some cython function call at initialization stage. Later on, I don't need them so I would like to clean it up. Also, each module has their own initialization. They may or may not call cython function. If cython is design as this way, there are only two way I can think of:
   1. keep python running all the time until application ends
   2. keep tracking each cython function calls and each module/client code need to track which cython module the function belong to and whether the module has been initialized.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you initialize and clean up twice? Just initialize once at the beginning of the program and then clean up once at the end.

Comment: That's a good question. In my application, I need python do something at beginning only. And different modules may need different cython functions calls to initialize their own data. Is it sound reasonable?